# Cannot get Python request GET to work with spitogatos.gr

Tags: web-scraping, cookies, get, python-requests

I've been trying to scrape the data from **[www.spitogatos.gr](http://www.spitogatos.gr)** but with no luck.
My code looks something like:

```
import requests

headers={
    'Host': 'www.spitogatos.gr',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://www.spitogatos.gr/',
'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
'Origin': 'https://www.spitogatos.gr'
}

url = "https://www.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r100/m2007m/propertyType_apartment/onlyImage"
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print (req)
print (req.content)
```

Although I get a response status 200, instead of any useful content I get the HTML message:

> Pardon Our Interruption As you were browsing something about your
> browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this
> might happen:
>
> You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser. You're a power user
> moving through this website with super-human speed. You've disabled
> cookies in your web browser. A third-party browser plugin, such as
> Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. ...

Now I had a look at Firefox to see what kind of request it sends, and although it sends a POST request I did copy the Cookie that Firefox sends with it's request. So my header would look something like:

```
headers={
    'Host': 'www.spitogatos.gr',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Referer': 'https://www.spitogatos.gr/',
'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
'Origin': 'https://www.spitogatos.gr',
'Cookie':'PHPSESSID=iielr7e8boibudjmln9ubd3i62; spitogatosS=areaIDs%255B0%255D%3D2007%26propertyCategory%3Dresidential%26listingType%3Dsale; currentCurrency=EUR; spitogatosInfoBar_shortCuts=false; openedTabs=; _ga=GA1.2.1557987790.1597249012; _gid=GA1.2.507964674.1597249012; _gat_UA-3455846-10=1; _gat_UA-3455846-2=1; _hjid=dfd027d6-e6f1-474c-a427-c26d5f2ca64c; _cmpQcif3pcsupported=1; reese84=3:T2t/w3VdpNG5w9Knf78l7w==:Gg20L4RyGJffieidEn4Eb1Hmb3wyAtPQfmH/5WYHWfKjzLmjhkGCoTR0j5UUmKxIbkzZltWBeJ6KaPVCFa5qiaddz2Cn6OltrBdp…2YIriDYTOwLMNNxEFPDPkL/Lw2cGC0MwJ3uUg6kSP/VgPp/AYkIcVjXLgqjSwmAdGl4oQDyrAKDpn9PcN/fWSUjPrtAOAJzkWcZ7FPCfvcsnAo9oSNpXtAaZ0JLzgMKXqQqP8Jrakjo4eL9TSdFKIVEJZos=:eBpByDUvhUkR0pGwgnYacTV3VeYzKEi+4pJpI3mhQ6c=; _fbp=fb.1.1597249012911.16321581; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; eupubconsent=BO4CN1PO4CN1PAKAkAENAAAAgAAAAA; euconsent=BO4CN1PO4CN1PAKAkBENDV-AAAAx5rv6_77e_9f-_fv_9ujzGr_v_e__2mccL5tn3huzv6_7fi_-0nV4u_1tfJdydkh-5YpCjto5w7iakiPHmqNeZ1nfmz1eZpRP58E09j53zpEQ_r8_t-b7BCHN_Y2v-8K96lPKACA; spitogatosHomepageMap=0'.encode('utf8')
}
```

Now when I do this the request will SOMETIMES work and sometimes it will give me the above message. So I keep refreshing Firefox and copy the Cookies over to my python script.
It is a hit and miss.

I have also been trying to replicate the exact POST request of firefox (identical data, params and headers) but this gives me the same error message.

Firefox does not seem to have this problem, no matter how many requests or refreshes I do.

Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `User-Agent` and `Accept-Language` I was able to get correct response every time (try to change `User-Agent` header to Linux one, as I have in example):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}
url = 'https://www.spitogatos.gr/search/results/residential/sale/r100/m2007m/propertyType_apartment/onlyImage'

print( requests.get(url, headers=headers).text )
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same "Bot-Message" happens with this one too. I think it may be server side. It will work if you haven't made any requests for a while, but if you do too many it will start complaining again. Firefox still seems to be ok though

Comment: @vzografos The site uses Cloudflare as CDN, so it will detect too many requests I think. Try to put `time.sleep()` between the requests.

Comment: Yes I just did that.  Let's see if it does something. What is really strange though is that it does not affect Firefox. Which makes me think it's not IP related. I tried modifying the user-agent in python after every request and it still blocks.  So my only hope is the time delay between requests

Comment: So I also tried with selenium by opening a Gecko webpage. This also throws this Bot message which is followed by a series of CAPTCHAs. So a solution is to attempt to scrape through Selenium, then pause until the CAPTCHA is manually solved and continue to scrape. Not sure why the Gecko browser gets flagged by Firefox doesnt. Must be the headers...

Comment: Hello, did you manage to sort this out and run flawlessly on Spitogatos?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem : the answer was so simple in fact. It's the "adblocker ultimate" that were the cause of the blockage.
So if you have some adds blockers, you could try to desactivate them, just to see, because the website could identify you as a bot when you use them.
But just to know, i have 3 adds blockers (addblock plus, ublock origin and adblocker ultimate) and it seems that only adblocker ultimate (installed very recently, while i have the others since months) caused the trouble.
I hope this solution could work for you too, if you're in the same case; or could help anybody else.